# Embedly Thumbnail - Blurred

Tags: meteor, telescope, embedly

In my Telescope App I integrated **Embedly Thumbnail**, the thumbnail is displaying but it is **very blur**. Do i need to change the width and height ratio or is there any option to make it look good.

Comment: Do you have some code to show us maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The Aspect Ratio should be correct only then the generated image will be good.
In the admin setting panel change the `width` and `height` property to your choice but maintain aspect ratio. I used `800x720`.

Answer (score 0):

The images may look blurry especially if you are using the Grid layout, which uses larger thumbnail images. In settings, try setting the thumbnail width and height to 700 and 350.